# .format.ps1xml not formatting class derived from list defined in c#

Tags: c#, powershell

I have a class like this in C#:

```
public class DerivedList : List<SomeType>
{
    public string SomeProperty= "DefaultValue";

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "ToString of DerivedList Class";
    }
}
```

and the following Format.format.ps1xml file:

```
<Configuration>
  <ViewDefinitions>
    <View>
      <Name>Namespace.DerivedList</Name>
      <ViewSelectedBy>
        <TypeName>Namespace.DerivedList</TypeName>
      </ViewSelectedBy>
      <ListControl>
        <ListEntries>
          <ListEntry>
            <ListItems>
              <ListItem>
                <Label>Items</Label>
                <PropertyName>Items</PropertyName>
              </ListItem>
              <ListItem>
                <Label>SomeProperty</Label>
                <PropertyName>SomeProperty</PropertyName>
              </ListItem>
            </ListItems>
          </ListEntry>
        </ListEntries>
      </ListControl>
    </View>
  </ViewDefinitions>
</Configuration>
```

But I can't get PowerShell to output the correct format. I suspect that it's because the formatting is derived from List, as other objects' formatting have worked for me. To update the format file, I called

```
Update-formatdata –prependpath "MyPath"
```

My goal is to print "SomeProperty : Value" at the end of the list without changing the return type (DerviedList), or returning an extra object. Is this possible?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `New-Object Namespace.DerivedList | Format-List -Expand CoreOnly`

Comment: @PetSerAl Is there a way to do that without requiring piping? Thanks!

Comment: `,,(New-Object Namespace.DerivedList)`